# Display empty state when using Google's Paging3 library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging

I'm currently using Google's Paging3 library for the first time. I'm basing my code on their Codelab at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#0.

The flow of my app adheres to the following rules:

1. display empty state
2. let users search for something
3. display results
4. when user presses back button on searchbar -> display empty state again

The codelab unfortunately does not deal with empty states :( I'm using the following addLoadStateListener to deal with the search results:

```
adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
            // Only show the list if refresh succeeds.
            binding.userRecyclerView.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.NotLoading
            // Show loading spinner during initial load or refresh.
            binding.progressBar.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Loading
            // Show the retry state if initial load or refresh fails.
            binding.errorMessage.isVisible = loadState.source.refresh is LoadState.Error
            if (binding.errorMessage.isVisible) {
                binding.errorMessage.text =
                    (loadState.source.refresh as LoadState.Error).error.toString()
            }
            binding.retryButton.isVisible = binding.errorMessage.isVisible

            // Toast on any error while loading more entries
            val errorState = loadState.source.append as? LoadState.Error
                ?: loadState.source.prepend as? LoadState.Error
                ?: loadState.append as? LoadState.Error
                ?: loadState.prepend as? LoadState.Error
            errorState?.let {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    resources.getString(R.string.error_loading),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
```

How can I use the addLoadStateListener to display the empty state? LoadState only has three possible values: NotLoading, Loading and Error. However, I do not always want to display the RecyclerView. It should only be visible when there are results AND the user has not pressed the back button.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction how I can do this? Is there some kind of best practice regarding this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple APIs you might find helpful:

You can use `PagingData.empty()` to create an empty `PagingData` you can submit to "clear" the previous `PagingData`, until you call `adapter.submitData` again. This is useful if you want to show empty state between searches or before searching. You can also use `PagingData.from(list)` if you want to show some static content.

To get the presented item count you can use `adapter.itemCount`

If you need to check specifically what items are loaded after refresh finishes, you can use `adapter.peek(index)` or `adapter.snapshot()` to get all the items at once (but is more expensive).

Comment: Should I clear the PagingData in the adapter? Where can I access the data it contains? (I'm returning the PagingData as a flow in my current network request)

Comment: You can only access the presented data in PagingDataAdapter. PagingData is just a thin wrapper around an internal event stream so it doesn't hold / cache any data. However, loadStateFlow is synchronous with adapter updates, so when REFRESH is NotLoading you can check the adapter state with the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: Makes sense :D I tried solving my problem like you described. Works like a charm! Thank you :)